# How to send return value to JS without stopping Python function

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I am using the `eel` module to communicate with Javascript (My Web UI). I have a loading screen while the python script is running. So I need my user to know what is the progress in python side while in loading screen.

So there is a function `myfunction` which is called from Web UI through Javascript. This function has around 5 stages. So I need to return the stage that the execution is currently in to be displayed on my loading screen. Now I only use a `return 'Done'` at the end of all stages. So that once all stages is finished the return value is displayed

```
eel.myfunction()(function (ret){
$('#status').text(ret)
})
```

How can I send a return value from python without stopping the function?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to have a function 'setLoadingFase' in you javascript and expose it to eel.
From the python you can call this function with the new loading fase you're in.

JS:

```
setLoadingFase(currentFase){
    console.log(currentFase)
}
eel.expose(setLoadingFase, 'set_loading_fase')
```

python:

```
@eel.expose
def load_program():
    ...
    eel.set_loading_fase("done with loading 1")
    ...
    eel.set_loading_fase("done with loading 2")
```

Comment: what is this string inside ```eel.expose(setLoadingFase, 'set_loading_fase')``` ??

Comment: That is the name of the function inside python. eel.set_loading_fase the set_loading_fase  comes from eel.expose(setLoadingFase, 'set_loading_fase')

Comment: Have you tried this ? I usually use ```eel.function_name_in_puthon()``` to call a function. So not sure how this ```ee.expose(function_name_in_puthon)``` works. Didn't see it in the Docs too.

Comment: That will also work. I work with react framework, that takes some extra steps

Comment: Oh I will surely test this out this week. I will make it as answer then.